# In bash script i want to save input

Tags: bash

This is my script:

```
read "email:" emailvar

read "user:" uservar

Echo "emailvar"  "uservar" > info.txt
```

In `info.txt` I found email and user but if make this again the old info aren't save.
I tried `>>` but not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
echo "$emailvar $uservar" > info.txt
```

...and read more about parameters (ie, variables) here:

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters